Movie where darkness kills you. Possibly ghosts?
I don't really remember how far back I watched it, but I'm almost sure it was in the early 2000's.
It started with this little boy in his room and something strange was happening. He was afraid of the dark. He ran out and his mom came. While she tried to convince him there's no reason to be afraid of the dark, she went in the room to prove it despite his warning. The darkness (or ghosts in it) killed her.
Then the scene moved to the present. Turns out he was locked up for killing his mom and everyone believed the rumor until the darkness started killing other people. The thing is, once they were in any amount of light, the darkness couldn't touch them unless they moved out of it.
I really want to rewatch this movie, can you help finding the title?

Darkness Falls is a 2003 American-Australian supernatural horror film written by Joe Harris and John Fasano and directed by Jonathan Liebesman. The film stars Chaney Kley and Emma Caulfield.
Mainly your description of the mother's death, and any light being the monster's weakness:

The story begins when Kyle Walsh, an antisocial teenager, befriended only by his secret crush, Caitlin Greene, loses his last baby tooth. That night he soon realizes the story of Matilda Dixon is not just a fable when he sees her in his bedroom. Matilda is now a vindictive spirit dressed in black robes and a white porcelain mask. Knowing that light is her weakness, he shines a flashlight into her face and hides in the bright lights of the bathroom. His mother, trying to convince him there's nothing in his room, is killed after seeing the Tooth Fairy. The next morning, as the police arrive, Kyle is taken to a mental hospital after mistaken speculations that he killed his mother.

The scene in question:



Are you afraid of the dark Tooth Fairy?

i think this is it. thank you!!
